# Empty product list on QueryProducts in Delphi XE6 TInappPurchase on Android

Tags: android, delphi, in-app-billing, delphi-xe6

I am developing inapp-Purchase in Delphi XE6.
Based on embarcadero documentation I create an InAppPurchase component as below:

```
        FInAppPurchase := TInAppPurchase.Create(self);
{$IFDEF Android}
        FInAppPurchase.ProductIDs.Add(License5And);
        FInAppPurchase.ProductIDs.Add(License10And);
        FInAppPurchase.ProductIDs.Add(License20And);
        FInAppPurchase.ProductIDs.Add(License50And);
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF IOS}
        FInAppPurchase.ProductIDs.Add(License5);
        FInAppPurchase.ProductIDs.Add(License10);
        FInAppPurchase.ProductIDs.Add(License20);
        FInAppPurchase.ProductIDs.Add(License50);
{$ENDIF}
        FInAppPurchase.OnSetupComplete := InAppPurchase1OnSetupComplete;
        FInAppPurchase.OnConsumeCompleted := InAppPurchase1ConsumeCompleted;
        FInAppPurchase.OnError := InAppPurchase1Error;
        FInAppPurchase.OnProductsRequestResponse := InAppPurchase1ProductsRequestResponse;
        FInAppPurchase.OnPurchaseCompleted := InAppPurchase1PurchaseCompleted;
        FInAppPurchase.OnRecordTransaction := InAppPurchase1RecordTransaction;
        FInAppPurchase.OnVerifyPayload := InAppPurchase1VerifyPayload;

{$IFDEF Android}
        FInAppPurchase.ApplicationLicenseKey := myLicenseKeyFromGoogleDeveloperConsole;
{$ENDIF}
```

Then in `InAppPurchase1OnSetupComplete` I Called the `FInAppPurchase.QueryProducts` then it goes into `InAppPurchase1ProductsRequestResponse` and `products` and `InavlidProductIDs` both are empty. I don't know what I missed. Any help will be appreciated.

I check my products in google developer console all of them are 'Active' and as Type of 'Managed'.

p.s. Code is working perfect on ios Device.

Comment: why -1??!! Down voting with out comments!!

Answer (score 2):

I lost a lot of time to understand the problem.
After I studied the source code I have understand that in Android the Events are asynchronous, you must wait the "QueryProducts" result.
In order to fix this problem I created a TTimer that wait 5 second before it read "InAppPurchase.IsProductPurchased"

(I'm sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the app should be published for alpha or beta testing.
Instead of uploading for production I need to upload it for alpha first then publish it. after that the products are shown.

Answer (score 0):

I developed the interface with the market starting from the example `CapitalITrivia` in `Enbarcadero`. I had the same problem and I read the answer that was given here.

I tried it and actually works. But this solution did not satisfy me because it depends on a delay not justified.

I realized that in `InAppPurchaseSetupComplete` was called the `QueryProducts` function and then I performed `IsProductPurchased`.

If I move the `IsProductPurchased` test in `InAppPurchaseProductsRequestResponse` function I get the expected result without introducing the delay.